# How to set up aws s3 with Heroku?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, heroku

I followed [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) to link my aws s3 bucket with my Heroku app.

In my s3 bucket I have a zip file called `model.zip`. I need to use this model in my app (Python). So after linking the bucket successfully according to the tutorial, I did the following:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('my-models-bucket', 'model.zip', 'model.zip')
```

But when I run it on Heroku, I get a 403 error at the `s3.download_file` line:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Do I need to specify the credentials in `boto3.client()`? I don't want to upload any credentials, so how should it be done? Or should I somehow use the environment variables I set up while linking s3 according to the tutorial? I.e. the tutorial says to do the following:

```
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=MY-ACCESS-ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=MY-ACCESS-KEY
Adding config vars and restarting app... done, v21
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     => MY-ACCESS-ID
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY => MY-ACCESS-KEY
```

Does that mean that I now have access to `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in my Python code and I should read them using `os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")` or something?

Or maybe there's something I should do on Aws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself after finding the solution...

I simply had to add a Policy to my s3 bucket, by going to the bucket > Permissions > Edit bucket policy > Policy generator > Fill up the fields and desired permissions (I only picked GetObject), generate the Policy, copy and paste it under Bucket Policy. Here's mine:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1234567",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1234567",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/my-user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now everything is working.